# extract a string between 2 quoted words in unix

Tags: unit-testing, unix

How to extract a string between 2 quoted words in unix?

A sample of it as below. Please note there is a pragraph in a file out of which below string should be extracted

"ABC":true,"EFG":"1.0.1","XYZ":"

Would like to extract: "EFG":"1.0.1"

Comment: Hi. This is quite difficult to answer, because the question doesn't match the example. The string between the 2 quoted words would be `:true,"EFG":"1.0.1",`. It seems as if You seek the string between the commas... that would be an easy one.

Comment: Sure but I have to just extract only "EFG":"1.0.1". Also have many other parameters in the file but am looking to extract only this particular text.

Answer (score 0):

The following will extract the second field from a comma-delimited file:

`awk -F, '{print $2}' /my/file`

Comment: Thanks how can we do the above recursively

Comment: Let say we have subdirectories and have to extract the string from a file

Comment: Nest the above code in a while loop.  

`find /sub/directory/ -type f | while read f; do awk -F, '{print $2}' "$f"; done`

You may need to alter the `find` command to filter out files that don't match the format you indicated.